# Parsing xml with PHP what to do with characters like these

Tags: php, xml, encoding, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml document using php.

When I see the result in my browser I get the following characters:

Ã± instead of spanish ñ

Ã­ instead of í

ÃƒÂ¡ instead of á

Ã³ instead of ó

Ã© instead of é

I was going to use a str_replace and replace every odd character for the good ones, but sadly the pattern before happens only sometimes and in general I have a wide collection of odd characters :(

The xml heading is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

But if I change it to utf-8 it simply won't be printed ..

I load the xml as a string with simplexml_load_string (comes from database like that)

Can you please give me any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that PHP displays these characters ok? Is your HTML output set as UTF?

Comment: This means UTF-8 data being misinterpreted as iso-8859-1.. you need to set utf-8 content-type header

Comment: In your browser, try changing character encoding under "View->Character Encoding" menu.  Once you find the one that displays correctly, use that in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

a) include a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');` before any output in your php file.

b) convert the output to utf-8 with `$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');`

Both should do the trick.

Comment: The data is already in utf-8, being misinterpreted as iso-8859-1 or similar. If you look at `Ã±` as ISO-8859-1, that's `C3B1`, and if you interpret `C3B1` in utf-8, you get `ñ`.

Comment: Yes! Yes! I love mb_convert_encoding ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXML` uses UTF-8 to encode stored strings. You can use an XML-File with iso-8859-1, but if you want to print XML values with this encoding, you have to use `utf8_decode` before.

Answer (score 0):

$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

```
// new xml
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('new.xml'); 

// Displaying XML in textual form
echo $xml->asXML();
```